# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use Class.set() instead

Tags: python, django

When I try to save Class which is in many to many relationship django throws the following error

```
TypeError at /class-create/
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use Class.set() instead.
```

My views.py looks like this

```
@login_required()
def create_class(request):
  tea_user = request.user.username
  validate = teacher_validation(tea_user)
  if validate:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        Link = request.POST.get('link')
        Subject = request.POST.get('Subject')
        Class = request.POST.get('Class')
        teacher_user = Teacher.objects.get(User=request.user)
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=teacher_user.id)
        created_class = Online_Class(Link=Link, Subject=Subject, Created_by =teacher, Class=Class)
        created_class.save()

    return render(request, 'online_class/Teacher/class-create.html')
  else:
       messages.warning(request, 'Sorry You Dont have Permission to access this page')
       return redirect('logout')
```

And my models.py file looks like this

```
class Online_Class(models.Model):
   Created_by = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   Class = models.ManyToManyField(Classes)
   Subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Link = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   Joined_by = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   choice = (('Yes','Yes'),('No', 'No'))
   Class_Ended = models.CharField(choices=choice, default='No', max_length=10)
```

Please help me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set `class=Class` in:

```
created_class = Online_Class(Link=Link, Subject=Subject, Created_by =teacher, Class=Class)
```

since `Class` is a `ManyToManyField`, and thus can not be set like that, you first create the `OnelineClass`, and then add an entry (or more entries) with `created_class.Class.set(&hellip)`:

```
@login_required
def create_class(request):
  tea_user = request.user.username
  validate = teacher_validation(tea_user)
  if validate:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        Link = request.POST.get('link')
        Subject = request.POST.get('Subject')
        Class = request.POST.get('Class')
        teacher_user = Teacher.objects.get(User=request.user)
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=teacher_user.id)
        created_class = Online_Class.objects.create(
            Link=Link,
            Subject=Subject,
            Created_by =teacher
        )
        created_class.Class.set([Class])

    return render(request, 'online_class/Teacher/class-create.html')
  else:
       messages.warning(request, 'Sorry You Dont have Permission to access this page')
       return redirect('logout')
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `OnlineClass` instead of <s>`Online_Class`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `class` instead of <s>`Class`</s>.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.